# cannot access api using LinkedIn v2/me

Tags: linkedin-api

I've successfully implemented LinkedIn `OAuth` functionality, but I need to retrieve some information from LinkedIn API.

When i access the API (v2/me), i get the below error:

> message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status": 403

Answer (score 0):

Common reasons you may get that error:

1. You didn't ask for the r_literprofile scope during the OAuth exchange.
2. You didn't pass the OAuth token (or passed it incorrectly).
3. Maybe you are asking for fields you're not authorized to access.

Hard to tell without more code from you.